# Photoshop resize circularly

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize

Is there a way to do this circular resize of a pattern in photoshop (flat image) ?
(I only want to resize the green disk, without changing the size of the interior white disk and without losing details of the green disk, just flatting them)

[image]

Comment: No, its not possible to change size of raster graphic without losing something. Its possible to do this yes but really requires you to be on top of your game.

Comment: By loosing details I don't mean loosing quality, I want all the content in the green disk to remain visible after the resize, flatten but visible.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question, but if the green circle and the white circle are on separate layers and you resize the green circle, the while circle won't be resized. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDsQe.gif - I used a white circle layer in this example, but if the center needs to be transparent, `White Circle` layer could just as well be made into [a layer mask on the `Textured Circle` layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyulN.png). Unlinked layer mask doesn't get resized with the layer it's attached to. Of course this doesn't squish the texture to fit the visible stroke.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done here are 4 approaches that work. No apprach is simple to do but its possible. I will describe the conceptually easiest option.

Option1: Using polar coordinates

1. Use the offset filter to move your circle center exactly to the middle of your document.
2. Apply polar coordinates.
3. Select the region that is now a strip in your image and scale it down.
4. Apply inverse polar
5. Inverse the offset

Done

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

An easy (not perfect) solution could be to use *Filter > Distort > Pinch*.

1. Make sure the circle is centered in your document.
2. Use *Filter > Distort > Pinch* and set *Amount* to a negative number.

If an *Amount* of *-100%* isn't enough, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to reapply the filter.

[image]

Afterwards, you can scale the circle down to the desired size.

Comment: This solution also does the job very well and more easily in my case but pattern will be more distorted than the other solution from joojaa. Thanks a lot!